# How to use Regular Expression in AWS CLI Filter

Tags: amazon-web-services, command-line-interface

I am using AWS Command Line Interface (CLI) to list some AMI Images from AWS.
The Name of an Image is like:

**XY_XYZ_Docker_1.13_XYZ_XXYY**

When using

```
aws ec2 describe-images --filters 'Name=name,Values="*_Docker_1.13_*"'
```

it works as expected.

Now i want to use Regular Expression instead of static value for the Name-Filter. 
In the AWS-Docs I read that filtering by RegEx [is possible](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/Using_Filtering.html)
My approach is:

**1:**

```
aws ec2 describe-images --filters 'Name=name,Values="[_]Docker[_][0-9][.][0-9]{2}[_]"'
```

The result is always *null* for this. I tried different ways of quoting the RegEx.

**2:**

```
[_]Docker[_][0-9][.][0-9]{2}[_]
```

(without quotes) leads to

> Error parsing parameter '--filters': Expected: ',', received: 'D' for input:
>   Name=name,Values=[*]Docker[*][0-9][.][0-9]{2}[_]

**3:**

```
 *[_]Docker[_][0-9][.][0-9]{2}[_]*
```

(with Asterisk) leads to

> Error parsing parameter '--filters': Expected: ',', received: ']' for input:
>   Name=name,Values=*[_]Docker[_][0-9][.][0-9]{2}[_]*

Comment: Would you consider piping the output of the AWS CLI to something like `grep`, and then using that tool's regular expression support?

Comment: I do not want to do that because I have some more filters and the Filter by name needs to be at the beginning

Comment: The AWS CLI uses JMESPath. See: [JMESPath Tutorial](http://jmespath.org/tutorial.html)

Answer (score 3):

I wasn't able to find if Jmespath or the --filters flag can support regex, so instead I just piped to Python to run through regex.

```
aws ec2 describe-images --filters 'Name=name,Values="*Docker*"' | \
python -c '
import json, sys, re
obj = json.load(sys.stdin)
matched_images = {"Images":[]}
for image in obj["Images"]:
  if len(re.findall(r"[Dd]ocker\s?[0-9][.][0-9]{2}", image["Name"])) > 0:
    matched_images["Images"].append(image)
print json.dumps(matched_images)
'
```

You can pipe the output (which is just a JSON string) to your next bash command if needed with a pipe character following the closing quote. Maybe this can address concerns with using grep since it returns a JSON string instead or regular text.

Answer (score 0):

See the gist below.
It covers:

- search ECR images sorted descending by imagePushDate
- selecting the tag that meets a Regex criteria
- using that to replace a key/value pair in a yaml

https://gist.github.com/pprogrammingg/69e7c85abede9822f2480e9b5e1e66fd